# How can I prevent Xcode from changing the color of my buttons?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

So I've done a button for my iPad app, and I saw something strange. When I run my app in the iOS 5 simulator, it changes the color, and the lines of my button become discontinuous. But when I push it, the button comes back to the right color, and the lines are ok. I think it's something that Xcode does automatically with any button, and I don't find the way to cancel it. Thank you for helping!

PS: The button code is so simple:

```
IBOutlet UIButton *button;
```

This is what it should look like:

[image]

And this is how it looks in the simulator:

[image]

Comment: Can you show us a screenshot of what you mean?

Comment: And also, show us how you've "done a button". Images, custom drawing, just setting colours?

Comment: ok, in ten minutes I'll upload it.

Comment: You probably didn't set the frame property of the button correctly. It would help, if you post the code that initializes your instance of `UIButton`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both tams and JacobFennell have good points, but you should also note that graphics are often represented much differently on the simulator than on a real device. You should try running your app on a device and see if the problem persists; I have had many 'problems' with custom buttons which turned out just to be improper rendering on the part of the simulator.

Comment: Yep! I tried the app in my friend's iPad, and, yes, it is ok. It's the iPad simulator that shows it in the wrong way!

Comment: The simulator is great, but *always* tests on real devices as well. Glad I could help!

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using the Interface builder, make sure that you are setting the button type to custom and that you have changed the behavior for all of the states. Under the dropdown menu of where you can set the type they also have StateConfig, where you can configure the look and text of your button for all of its different states: highlighted, default, disabled...Check that those settings are correct as well.

Hope this helps!
Tams

Answer (score 1):

Your button frame size doesn't seem to match the size of your image. Your art should match the (button/view) frame size pixel for pixel, otherwise you may get blurry images and scaling representation artifacts.

Else, you can change the view content mode (UIViewContentMode) of the frame from `UIViewContentModeScaleToFill` to `UIViewContentModeTopLeft`